# teradata sql optimization help test query

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need help on some teradata sql optimization code. The below code I am running just to see if this returns any records. This query has been running for 19 minutes already. I just need a fast query to see if there are any results from the query. How can I optimize this test query? I just need to see if this returns any results for any day of the month. It looks like the primary key is txn_id and table partition is PRD_END_DT. Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT top 2000 PRD_END_DT, RECORD_ID, TRAN_DIM_NB, TXN_ID, APPL_ID, CHANNEL_ID,
        ENTRY_DATE_DT, ENTRY_DATE_TM, SERVER_ID, SRC_ENTRY_DATE_DT, SRC_ENTRY_DATE_TM,
        USER_ID, USER_ID_TYPE, TXN_TYPE, SESSION_ID, TXN_CAT_CD, UNQ_TXN_ID
FROM    ICDW_FL_GBL_V.LDA_CIG_TXNS_SLT_TXN_DAILY
 where prd_end_dt = to_date('08/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: Can you post the explain plan? Also, how is the partition defined? Maybe try      PARTITION BY RANGE_N (prd_end_dt BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2020-01-01' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY); (Range of course should be modified based on your data and needs)

Comment: how many rows  you have in table?

Comment: The size of Spool 2 is estimated with high confidence
     to be 71,434,829 rows (16,072,836,525 bytes).

Comment: Is `ICDW_FL_GBL_V.LDA_CIG_TXNS_SLT_TXN_DAILY` a table or a view? If it's a table a `TOP` (without ORDER) should run sub-second, if not it might be blocked.

Comment: Btw, the shortest reliable way to write a date is based on Standard SQL: `prd_end_dt = DATE '2017-08-01'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT top 2000 PRD_END_DT
      , RECORD_ID
      , TRAN_DIM_NB
      , TXN_ID
      , APPL_ID
      , CHANNEL_ID
      , ENTRY_DATE_DT
      , ENTRY_DATE_TM
      , SERVER_ID
      , SRC_ENTRY_DATE_DT
      , SRC_ENTRY_DATE_TM
      , USER_ID
      , USER_ID_TYPE
      , TXN_TYPE
      , SESSION_ID
      , TXN_CAT_CD
      , UNQ_TXN_ID
FROM    ICDW_FL_GBL_V.LDA_CIG_TXNS_SLT_TXN_DAILY
WHERE prd_end_dt = to_date('08/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

be sure you have a valid index (secondary index)  on  table `ICDW_FL_GBL_V.LDA_CIG_TXNS_SLT_TXN_DAILY` column `prd_end_dt`

```
CREATE INDEX your_idx (prd_end_dt) ON LDA_CIG_TXNS_SLT_TXN_DAILY;
```

Comment: If the table is actually partitioned by `prd_end_dt` a Secondary  Index on the same column would be useless.